# Returning a Boolean and a variable at same time in a function ? Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pass-by-reference

Is it possible to return a boolean and a variable from a function in python

```
def foo(self, x):
    if x > 5:
       y = 2  #for workaround with pass by reference method 
       return true , y

# calling it by
i = 0
for i in range (0,10): 
    if foo(i):
        ref_value = y  #to get the reference value
```

Comment: "for workaround with pass by reference method" - Python doesn't have pass by reference. `y = 2; return True, y` is exactly the same as `return True, 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your above code returns a `tuple` , you can return multiple values like that (in a tuple or a list, etc) , but you will have to accept them (*unpack*) all at the calling side as well (either accept them all, or accept the tuple/list as a single element). Example/Demo -

```
>>> def foo(i):
...     if i > 5:
...             y = 2
...             return True, y
...     return False,0
...
>>> for i in range(0,10):
...     x,y = foo(i)
...     if x:
...             ret_value = y
...     else:
...             ret_value = 0
...     print(ret_value)
...
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
2
2
>>> type(foo(6))        #Example to show type of value returned.
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to unpack both values from the returned result:

```
i = 0
for i in range (0,10):
    cond, y = foo(i) 
    if cond:
        ref_value = y
```